# Is there a better way of checking the type in a datarow?

Tags: c#, c#-3.0

I have to check whether the first cell in my datarow is a datetime object.I'm doing the following for it.Could you please let me know whether there is a better way to do it?

```
public bool ShouldProcess(DataRow theRow)
        {
            try
            {                
                Convert.ToDateTime(theRow[0]);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }
```

Thanks,
-M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `if (theRow[0] is DateTime)`?

Answer (score 1):

No need to place `try/catch`

```
DateTime outDate =  null;
DateTime.TryParse(theRow[0], out outDate);
if(outDate != DateTime.MinDate)
{
//Successfully converted
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
if(theRow[0] is DateTime)
    return true;
else
    return false
```

The `is` keyword checks the type of the left-hand side to see whether it is compatible with the type given on the right-hand side.

Answer (score 0):

Rather have a look at using

[DateTime.TryParse Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparse%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)  or even [DateTime.TryParseExact Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

Remember that these Methods return a bool value, so you can use it to return the bool value.

something like

```
DateTime dateVal;
return DateTime.TryParse(theRow[0], out dateVal);
```